# Ubuntu 20.04 gnome sound: how to prevent device switching

Tags: gnome, sound

### Background

I'm working on a project which produces a piece of hardware that comes up as audio input (think a USB microphone), and every time the device is reloaded the default input device switches to the new audio device.

I have to switch back in order to actually debug and diagnose my project.  Additionally it makes startup issues hard to deal with.

### Question

Is it possible to tell the audio stack not to auto-switch inputs, or to explicitly make it ignore a single input (or single device type).

Is this switching at the Gnome settings layer? Gnome audio management (ie related to volume control outside the settings "app")? or pulseaudio? or some integration between the pieces.

Is there somewhere that the Ubuntu audio stack architecture is documented?

I suspect it is not pulseaudio itself since normally PA notes the arrival of new devices, but doesn't switch, but then I don't know how gnome controls PA to provide the gnome audio experience.

Comment: Have a look at `/etc/pulse/default.pa` Look for `load-module module-switch-on-connect`

Comment: Thanks - that's perfect - is there a standard way to override pulse-audio config that won't interfere with Ubuntu's management thereof? I see adding a file to .config, that includes the one from /etc, which works for _adding_ to that file, but not sure how you would remove from that file?

Answer (score 0):

From the manual: "The  PulseAudio  sound  server  interprets  a configuration script on startup, which is mainly used to define the set of modules to load. When PulseAudio runs in the per-user mode and ~/.config/pulse/default.pa exists, that file is used. When PulseAudio  runs  in the  per-user  mode  and  that  file  doesn't  exist,  /etc/pulse/default.pa is used."
So, copy /etc/pulse/default.pa to ~/.config/pulse/default.pa and comment out the line containing "load-module module-switch-on-connect".